# parse error syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, html, string, syntax

I am getting the syntax error commented code. Can some have idea, why this error comes

Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

```
echo '<script>
    alert("Case successfully assigned!");
    window.location.href="casedetails.php?caseid=".$row['case_id']."&&msg=added ";
    </script>';
```

Comment: in url you have to pass single & not &&

Comment: Most of the time i used `&amp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the single quotes and single & like :

`'.$row['case_id'].'&msg=added"`

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to open and close. Don't mix it :
Try this

```
echo '<script>
    alert("Case successfully assigned!");
    window.location.href="casedetails.php?caseid='.$row['case_id'].'&&msg=added";
    </script>';
```

Comment: the double quote mess up everythings. Now it worked. Thank

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate properly, you started with single quotes...try

```
echo '<script>
alert("Case successfully assigned!");
window.location.href="casedetails.php?caseid='.$row['case_id'].'&msg=added";
</script>';
```